# Perform a query in Spring Data JPA using an Example to get only the First Projection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In Spring Data, I have a [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to get only `Id` of my `Entity`.

```
public interface IdOnly<T> {
    T getId();
}
```

I need to filter my query by many fields, many of them can be *null* and the null values should not be used in the query. So, I intended to use [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) to do the job. Besides that, I need to get just **the first one Id**, [limiting the query on database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result). But unfortunately, it seems like there is no way to do that.

```
// It works
IdOnly<Long> findFirstBy();

// It works too (although it does not limit the query in database)
Entity findOne(Example<Entity> example);

// It doesn't work. Throws an ClassCastException when returns a non-null entity
IdOnly<Long> findOne(Example<Entity> example);

// That's the one I really need
// The server doesn't start (IndexOutOfBoundsException)
IdOnly<Long> findFirstBy(Example<Entity> example);
```

So, is there any way to do a query like that, using an Example, to get only the First projection?

[Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

[Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)

[Limiting query results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Answer (score 0):

I really couldn't do it using all three Spring's facilities. So, I preferred to use [Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) because of the extensive code to test all the fields and get the predicates. This way it's easier to make different queries using the ease of [Query By Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).

```
import static org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.QueryByExamplePredicateBuilder.getPredicate;

@Service
public class EntityService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Long findFirstById(Entity entity) {
        return getId(em, Entity_.id, Example.of(entity), Entity.class, Long.class);
    }

    private static <E, N> N getId(EntityManager em, SingularAttribute<E, N> id, Example<E> example, Class<E> entityClass, Class<N> idClass) {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<N> cq = cb.createQuery(idClass);
        final Root<E> from = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(from.get(id)).where(getPredicate(from, cb, example));
        return em.createQuery(cq).setMaxResults(1).getResultList().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}
```